# Business catalyst prototype-core.ashx Refused to set unsafe header "Connection" conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, business-catalyst

I currently use Adobe Business Catalyst on an ecommerce site and it run into the same problem:

When clicking add to cart the log shows:

**prototype-core.ashx Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"**

all custom javascript I have and jQuery breaks and does not ready some functions.

I tried using methos such as [jQuery noConflicts();](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Still nothing works well, I cant provide a sample code because everything is working from the server and I use another method to have a work around it for the time being.

Any suggestions please advise.

Comment: Take a look at this [forum thread at Adobe](https://forums.adobe.com/message/5613007). It should help give you some guidance.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a callback to the error the console provides: 

prototype-core.js:1 Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"invoke @ prototype-core.js:1
VM2245:10 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :(…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look into the prototype-core.ashx you will find this

```
if(!MS.Browser.isIE) {
        this.xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close") // Mozilla Bug #246651
    }
```

This is not an issue, it is just a line of code your browser does not understand, if you use Mozilla you will not see this error in your console, but you will see a bunch of different warnings.

There is quite a lot on Stack**overflow** about the issue that **JavaScript** doesn't work after an **Ajax** call.
What you can do to fix it is call all your functions again after the add to cart button has been pressed.

So first I have my JavaScript functions FirstFunction(); SecondFunction(); ThirdFunction(); and then I call them like this

```
function FirstFunction() {
    //do whatever you want to do
}
function SecondFunction() {
    //do whatever you want to do
}
function ThirdFunction() {
    //do whatever you want to do
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    // do it once onload
    FirstFunction();
    SecondFunction();
    ThirdFunction();
    $('.main_content').on('click',function() {
        // do it again onclick
        FirstFunction();
        SecondFunction();
        ThirdFunction();
    });
});
```

This way all your functions are loaded again when you click on inside `.main_content`.

Comment: I have worked it out this way before and still is the best way but I would not call it the most efficient way to fix the problem, perhaps an additional function to the prototype to ignore functions operating in the DOM would be a best approach.